# How to highlight the updates from a Cognito Form

Tags: cognito-forms

Can I highlight the changes that take place during entry update?
The scope is to have these highlights in notification emails among entry data.

Answer (score 1):

I work for Cognito Forms support. That's a great idea.  It's not something we do currently.  I'll add it to the [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/db8eNYZT/254-highlight-changes-or-otherwise-provide-history-of-updated-entries).